# spring cron for last Tuesday of every month

Tags: spring, cron, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I need to set cron job for every month's last Tuesday at 23:45 in a spring boot application,
I got 2 expressions but not sure whether they are correct or not

1. `0 45 23 L * 2`
2. `0 45 23 ? * 2L`

I've made another expression that runs on every fourth Tuesday(`0 45 23 ? 1/1 TUE#4 *`), but some months have 5 Tuesdays,

Please tell a cron expression that run on every last Tuesday of the month.
Thanks in advance.

I tried,

1. `0 45 23 L * 2`
2. `0 45 23 ? * 2L`
3. `0 45 23 ? 1/1 TUE#4 *`

expecting a cron job expression that runs on last Tuesday of every month

Answer (score 0):

`0 45 23 ? * 3L` - Last Tuesday of every month.

You can try it at [Java Cron Website](https://www.javainuse.com/cron), [Free formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)

```
1L - Sunday
2L - Monday
3L - Tuesday
4L - Wednesday
5L - Thursday
6L - Friday
7L - Saturday
```

As Sunday is the first day and Saturday is last day of the week.